# ¿Cómo incluyo un quiebre de línea en un string en Delphi?

Tags: delphi

Quiero crear un string que abarque múltiples líneas para asignarlo a la propiedad `Caption` de un `TLabel` en Delphi:

```
Label1.Caption = 'Hola' + ?? + 'Mundo';
```

Y visualmente quede:

```
Hola
Mundo
```

¿Cómo logro hacerlo en Delphi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La unidad `System.pas` (que se utiliza de manera automática en cualquier unidad de Delphi) tiene la siguiente definición:

```
const
  sLineBreak = {$IFDEF POSIX} _AnsiStr(#10) {$ENDIF}
      {$IFDEF MSWINDOWS} _AnsiStr(#13#10) {$ENDIF};
```

El código está tomado de Delphi 10.2 Rio, pero hay una asignación equivalente en todas las versiones a partir de Delphi 6 (aproximadamente).

Utilizar esta constante garantiza que se añadirá el *quiebre de línea* correcto para la plataforma en que se compile el ejecutable.

Entonces, para hacer que un `TLabel` tenga dos líneas, asegúrate que tiene la propiedad `AutoSize` en `True` y luego utiliza un código similar al siguiente:

```
Label1.Caption := 'Hola' + sLineBreak + 'Mundo';
```

Con información de [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/254997/255257)(en inglés).

Answer (score 0):

Simplemente en medio de la frase se agrega un char(13):

Ejemplo :

`Label1.Caption := 'Hola' + char(13)+ 'Mundo';`

Hola

Mundo